# Citations in \include latex code result in [?]

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have a main file which includes another file of text with citations using \cite{}. The citations I include in the text don't work and when I compile it I get [?].

The citations are listed properly at the end of the document though when compiled in the references list. Any idea how I can get the citations to show up in the included text?

I put a bare bones example below to try to show what I mean. I am sure several required packages are missing here... Thanks for any help you can give!

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \include{otherFile}
  \bibliographystyle{siam}
  \bibliography{myCitations}
\end{document}
```

otherFile.tex

```
Some text here I want to include with a citation \cite{citation1}
```

myCitations.bibl

```
@Article{citation1,
  author =       "author",
  title =        "{Title}",
  journal =      "Journal",
  year =         "2004",
  volume =       "109",
  number =       "C18",
  pages =        "C08007", %  C08007.1-C08007.12",
  doi =          {10.1029/testingdoi},
}
```

Comment: you have not provided a usable test file, bibtex will need a `\bibliographystyle` command, also you tagged this biblatex but you seem to be using bibtex not biblatex.  Have you run latex enough times to resolve all citation references, you would expect to need to run latex twice after running bibtex

Comment: For citation purposes, `\include` acts as if the contents of the file are at that point, and does not affect anything.  But you need to be sure to run latex, then bibtex, and then latex at least twice more.  Are you doing that?

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you for your comment. The project I have is a template for a thesis and is very sophisticated so I provided a bare bones example. I know the example I have is missing things like the \bibliographystyle you mentioned among other packages but I just wanted to give an idea. I do have those things in practice and was being a bit lazy with my question. I apologize for that. I just don't know how I can get the citations to show up from the include text.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thank you for your comment. am using Overleaf and I have tried to compile multiple times. Should I be doing something different there?

Comment: I did just try a citation within the main.tex file and that worked. So it only doesn't work if I try to cite something in the \include{} text.

Comment: `\include` should not affect the citation system so unless you provide a usable test file that shows the problem then there really isn't a lot of help that can be given

Comment: are you using `\includeonly` ?

Comment: I am using \include ... Let me try to get a more substantial test file. Give me a few moments please and I will edit the post.

Comment: Try if it works if you use \input instead of \include.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you so much \input seems to have worked :) Thank you everyone for chiming in to help me out!

Comment: only one line of your extended example is any use to anyone helping `\bibliographystyle{siam}`  any example code should be something we can run to see the problem and test answers, you should remove all unrelated packages not needed to show the problem and all \include or \input of local files you have not shown

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidCarlisle. That is really useful to know. I am familiar with Latex but this template I was given is more advanced than what I have used before. I really appreciate the help :) I will edit the question as you suggest.